# Nautilus/Samba Mount Problem

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, samba, cifs

On a laptop with Ubuntu 10.04, I have several Nautilus bookmarks to mount various Windows (7 and 2003) shares on my home network, accessed thru OpenVPN. I have full rights to all of these shares, and until recently I was able to mount them via Nautilus and read/write them fine. Now I still mount fine, but all seem to be RO now. When browsing one of the shares in Nautilus, paste is greyed out, and any file I attempt to drag/drop on the share "bounces" back and does not copy/move. I can, however, from a shell go to the .gvfs folder the share is mounted at, and am able to read/write via the command line just fine. I can also mount the shares via "mount -t cifs" just fine from the command line, and access is normal. It appears Nautilus is blocking writes to any of these shares. 
What's changed?? Help!!

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bug affecting you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/447695 and the reason why you could write and you cant anymore.

It will be fixed on the next release from Ubuntu. Maybe a early upgrade would be advised to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the bugs.launchpad search.. I'd tried looking there, but came up with nothing.. Wonderful.. :-< I stick to LTS releases since I don't have time to keep up with the 6 month upgrade treadmill.. You'd think on a bug as nasty as this, they'd backport a fix for us LTS people... Not gonna upgrade just to fix a bug..